# Display parent records that meet condition of child records

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle18c

In oracle sql, imagine I have a table of game developers and a table of products  sold by a game store. Imagine I am trying to select only game developers that have a total amount of products available at the game store that is less than 10.

For the sake of this, I will call the tables 'Developers' and 'Games'. Developers contains a PK of DEV_ID which will serve as the FK of GAME_DEV in Games.

```
CREATE TABLE Developers (
DEV_ID varchar(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DEV_NAME varchar(20) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Games (
GAME_ID varchar(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
GAME_NAME varchar(20) NOT NULL,
GAME_PRICE varcher(10) NOT NULL,
GAME_DEV varchar(5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT game_fk FOREIGN KEY (GAME_DEV)
REFERENCES Developers(DEV_ID));
```

I have tried doing something like creating a view, and then trying to select only the DEV_ID from the view where the amount of entries is less than 10. Heres what ive tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW games_developers AS
SELECT * FROM Games g
INNER JOIN Developer d
ON g.GAME_DEV = d.DEV_ID;

SELECT DEV_ID FROM games_developers
WHERE COUNT(DEV_NAME) < 10;
```

Now I get the error message "group function is not allowed here" 
Any ideas of how I can pull a list of developers who only have an available amount of games at the store that is less than 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Developer d
WHERE d.DEV_ID IN (SELECT g.GAME_DEV
                   FROM Games g
                   GROUP BY g.GAME_DEV
                   HAVING COUNT(*) < 10
                  );
```

However, this will miss developers with *no* games in the store.  So:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Developer d
WHERE d.DEV_ID NOT IN (SELECT g.GAME_DEV
                       FROM Games g
                       GROUP BY g.GAME_DEV
                       HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
                      );
```

Comment: does this only work with the view that I already created or does it work with the original tables whether or not the view exists?

Comment: Actually I figured out it works with just the tables. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which may or may not be any clearer

```
select d.dev_id, d.dev_name, count(*) num_games
  from developer d
       left outer join games g
         on( d.dev_id = g.game_dev )
 group by d.dev_id, d.dev_name
having count(*) < 10
```

If you changed your view to do a `left outer join` instead, then you could just do

```
select d.dev_id, d.dev_name, count(*) num_games
  from games_developers d /* If the view does an outer join */ 
 group by d.dev_id, d.dev_name
having count(*) < 10
```